# HTML sliding bars?

Tags: javascript, html

how does one create a sliding bar using HTML? 
I cannot seem to find anything in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [JQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)

[(Yet another JavaScript question that is answered with JQuery)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Answer (score 8):

HTML5 does, in fact, have [support for sliders](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#type-range):

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="2" value="6">
```

> ...browsers are expected to render
>   type="range" as a slider control. At
>   time of writing, the latest versions
>   of Safari, Chrome, and Opera all do
>   this. (Sadly, the iPhone renders it as
>   a simple text box. It doesn’t even
>   optimize its on-screen keyboard for
>   numeric input.) All other browsers
>   simply treat the field as type="text",
>   so there’s no reason you can’t start
>   using it immediately. ([diveintohtml5.ep.io](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/))